# Saving page state in a 3 page app in WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, page-lifecycle

Well it's my first question here and as far as i searched i didn't find a solution for my problem. I am coding my first rssreader app for WP7 and i am facing a problem with the page state. I have 3 pages and navigation goes like that
mainpage >>> listitemspage >>> detailspage. Mainpage is a databound model with preconfigured feeds category items (urls and names), listitempage is a page in which i implemented a webclient to read feed items and detailspage is where i pass the details of the selected feed item from listitempage. Page state working in these situations:

```
mainpage >>> start button >>> back button (OK)<br/>
listitempage >>> start button >>> back button (Doesn't work)<br/>
detailspage >>> start button >>> back button (OK)<br/>
```

In detailspage i save the page state using OnNavigatedTo/From and State.TryGetValue
This seems to work but if i create a button with a browser task so the user can navigate to the full article when the browser open and user press back button the details page state works. If the user press for second time the back button then the app is exiting instead of navigating back to the listitempage. So i have this problem too:

```
detailspage >>> browserbuttontask >>> backbutton >>> restorepage >>> backbutton->exit<br/>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the Tombstone helper on codeplex written by Matt Lacey (of the Windows Phone User Group).

http://tombstonehelper.codeplex.com/

It will either solve all your problems very easily or at the very least show you how to write your page states off to isolated storage for long term use (remember the state cache only survives while the device is powered and so long as the phone doesn't need to clear it's memory)

Hope this helps
Rgds
Simon

Comment: Thanks for the reply Darkside. I have already used this with no results. Unfortunatelly with the Tombstone Helper didn't even have the details page state correctly saved. The method i use for saving the current page state of the details page is working perfect (except the problem with the browser task) but i want something similar for the listitemspage too and i have run out of ideas. I would like to do it with page state without messing aroung with isolated storage.If that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save page state without messing with IsolatedStorage try SterlingDB.  It uses IsolatedStorage but it is very simple to setup and use.  You can add sterling via nuget.  You will have to stick data you want persisted in a class but saving and loading is simple.

Beyond that you also might want to look at [Caliburn](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Working%20with%20Windows%20Phone%207%20v1.1&referringTitle=Documentation) Micro. It adds page lifecycle to your ViewModels like OnInitialize, OnActivate, OnDeactivate.  It also adds some nice stuff for WP7 like automagically persisting properties on a ViewModel to IsolatedStorage or phone state.

http://www.sterlingdatabase.com/

Comment: Thanks Derek for your suggestions. Although they are looking too difficult for me to implement them (i am a begginer yet). Let's focus at the moment on how to restore data from the listitemspage . I tried to implement OnNavigatedTo/From and State.TryGetValue on that page but i guess that when the OnNavigateTo is been called, the page never reloaded in order to run the webclient event to fetch the items. Is there any way to do it like that?

Comment: So when you hit the browser your apps back stack is wiped.  And the reason it does go back to your details page is because it's in the browsers back stack.  At that point you'll need some logic to figure out where you came from and where it should go on another back button.  Check out http://buildmobile.com/windows-phone-7-navigation/ to see how you can subscribe to the OnBackKeyPress event.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your application is throwing an exception when restoring state to your list page, which has the effect of terminating the application.

Have you tried doing all this with the debugger attached? It should show you what exception is being thrown and where.

Comment: I updated my code with the new mango SDK and state handling is working fine now. Thanks guys for your replies!